# Randomizer between set images no more than length

Tags: javascript

```
var products = jQuery( ".products" );
products.addClass('none_display');
products.each(function (index) {
    if (index < 12)
         jQuery(this).addClass('block_display');
});
function getRandomImage(allBanners){
    var mqa = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 768px)" );
    if (mqa.matches) {
        var allBannersAll = jQuery('.products');
        if (allBanners === undefined)
            allBanners = allBannersAll;
        else {
            allBanners = '.products.'+allBanners;
            allBanners = jQuery(allBanners);
        }
        timerId = setInterval(function () {
            allBannersAll.addClass('none_display');
            allBannersAll.removeClass('block_display');
            var totalAllBanners = allBanners.length;
            allBanners.each(function (index) {
                if (index < 12 ){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('block_display');
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('none_display');          
                    // allBannersAll.eq(random2).show();
                    // var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * allBanners.length);
                    // allBanners.eq(random3).show();
                }
                images_vis_inv();
            });
        }, 4000);
         function images_vis_inv(){
            var visible,
                non_visible;
                    visible = jQuery(".products.block_display").length;
                    non_visible = jQuery(".products.none_display").length;
                    non_visible_single = jQuery(".products");
             non_visible_sing  = jQuery(".products.none_display");
             visible_sing  = jQuery(".products.none_display");
             var randomShow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (non_visible));
             var randomHide = Math.floor(Math.random() * (visible )) ;
             non_visible_single.eq(randomShow).addClass('block_display').removeClass('none_display');
             non_visible_single.eq(randomHide).addClass('none_display').removeClass('block_display');
             console.log('----------------------------'+randomHide +'///'+randomShow);
            }
    }
}
```

Hi, 
I have a set amount of images that are brought with php. Currently I displayed only 12 of them, and the rest are hidden with display none. I need to randomize between the hidden ones and the visible. For example, the visible images are changed by the hidden ones, but the number of them is always 12, no more no less. How can I achieve this in the function images_vis_inv ?Thank you for the help.

Comment: When the "next" set of 12 are displayed are they randomly chosen from all the images or from the images that are not currently on display?

Comment: Not currently on display, the ones with display none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be a bad idea to look at using a data structure to store your product information and display 8 at a time rather than maintaining DOM elements for each of the many products.  Just something to think about.

For now, I have attempted to follow what I am guessing is your current implementation as much as I can.

The crux of this uses an array of your product elements that we mix up every few seconds with a *shuffle*.  The shuffled elements are then "re-added" to their parent in the new order.

There are lots of ways to improve this, but it might do what you want out of the box and the code is fairly straight forward.

Per your request, I have altered this little demo to use actual images rather than background colors.  It might take a few iterations to load the images.

```js
// ======================
// A derivation of Fisher-Yates
// ======================
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
// ======================

var allProducts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product"));

setInterval(function(){
  var currentProducts = allProducts.splice(0,3);
  shuffleArray(allProducts);
  allProducts = allProducts.concat(currentProducts);
  allProducts.forEach(function(product){ product.parentNode.appendChild(product); })
}, 4000);
```

```css
.product {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

/* only show the first "3" children */
.product:nth-child(-n+3) { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="allProducts">
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/dog);">01</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/cat);">02</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/bird);">03</div>

  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/paris);">04</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/rio);">05</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/london);">06</div>

  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/boy);">07</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/girl);">08</div>
  <div class="product" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/100/100/ball);">09</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it shuffles between set images, not the hidden ones, my html is at follows. Really thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment.  In this code, the individual divs are represented by a color, but that could be easily switched to an image.  I just did not want to look for a dozen images to use.  The first 3 divs are displayed, the rest are "hidden".  Would it help if I used images rather than background color?

Comment: I updated the code to use images rather than colors.